# How can I map over my image src array when using Grid cards bootstrap in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5

I am trying to generate 6 cards with 6 different images, however, I am having a hard time figuring out how I can map it. There are no errors whatsoever and the card isn't showing the corrupt thumbnail as well but the card doesn't display the image from the array.

[Code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlrNX.png)

Comment: Would be much easier to show you what's wrong if you copied and pasted your code here.

Comment: @codemonkey Kindly see the attachment.